# Conditional on attributes html

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui

I have a element on html (kendo-chart) who can have two or four attributes on it, depending of a variable. My question is about how can I do this.

Thanks!

What I have tried:

1.- I tried putting a if on the attribute like this:

```
[pannable]="isLowChart ? { lock: 'y' }: null"
```

but it doesnt work because all charts can panneable

2.- I used a viewchild to try in angular add the attributes:

```
this.kendoChart.pannable = { lock: 'y' };
```

but it doesnt work because nothing happens

```
<kendo-chart #kendoChart [transitions]="false"
      (seriesHover)="onSeriesHover($event)"
      [pannable]="isLowChart ? { lock: 'y' }: null"
      [zoomable]="isLowChart ? { mousewheel: { lock: 'y' }, selection: { lock: 'y' } }: null">
```

[panneable] and [zoomable] are the attributes which Im trying to make dynamic